# I'm looking for a simple code sample that shows how to rotate a cube with text

Tags: html

I've been tasked with creating an HTML5 demo that basically consists of a rotateable cube. Each face should have different text on it, and then when you tap a face it should animate itself so that the face expands to fill the entire screen.

Are there any good (simple) tutorials out there that show how to do this? Everything I've found so far is excessively complex and appears to contain a great deal more code than just what I need. I have a basic understanding of HTML elements and javascript.

Comment: Well, tap or click. It's meant to run in a browser, on a Mac, PC, iPad etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out whats going on at http://www.htmlfivewow.com/slide44 which tackles most of your cube needs. Hit right key a few times and you'll see it going. You should be able to work from that. It's all just `<div>`s.